# Change data from a specific position in the ListView

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-studio

How I can change data in a certain position of the `ListView`.

Here I get the database to the `ListView`:

```
public void carregarEmails(Cliente cliente) {
    ArrayList<Email> listaView = dao.pegarResultListaEmail(cliente);
    listaEmail.setAdapter(new ClienteCadEmailBaseAdapter(getActivity(), listaView));
}
```

Code that retrieves data from the selected row :

```
private void informacaoSelecionadaEmail(View v) {
    listaEmail = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lstEmails);
    listaEmail.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object o = listaEmail.getItemAtPosition(position);
            objEmail = (Email) o;
            posicaoEmail = position;
            edtEmail.setText(objEmail.getEmail());
        }
    });
}
```

However, to get the changed `EditText` and send it to the line again is what I have no idea how to do.

Thx for all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with a `ListView` and an `Adapter`, if you want to update a data you have

- to update the data inside the adapter
- call the [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method

Answer (score 0):

Change your data in the ArrayList and after you can call yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();